# How can I get a 'Group Seperator', 0x1D, character from Text box or Rich Textbox or ETC. C#

Tags: c#, noncharacter

I use a USB 2D barcode scanner scan a GS1 Datamatix to key in the barcode text via USB to a computer like a keyboard. The text uses 'Group Seperator', 0x1D, character as a delimiter.

When I put cursor in a Hex/Text editor then scan, the 'Group Seperator' is there.

But when I put cursor in textbox at Interaction.InputBox, the 'Group Seperator' is disappear.

From an input text box or etc., If I want the 'Group Seperator' appear in string or byte array, how can I do that?

Note: I've tried by using Textbox and Rich Textbox, also cannot get the character.

Thank you.

.

Appendix

Scan a GS1 Datamatix in a Hex/Text editor. The text information contains 'Group Seperator', 0x1D, character

[image]

Scan a GS1 Datamatix in Interaction.InputBox. The 'Group Seperator', 0x1D, is missing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the KeyDown event to catch the {GS} char
I added all the characters to a List and search for it after the ENTER

`List<char> charList = new List<char>();`

in the KeyDown function:

```
charList.Add(e.KeyChar);
```